# jqxGrid: conditionally add edit button per row

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jqxgrid

i have jqxGrid and display data fine using ajax request and everything is workig fine .
My problem : in grid coulmns i added edit button but i want to add this button conditionally depended on values of another  field

My Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnsearchHistory").click(function () {
        var txtfrom = $('#txtfrom').val();
        var txtto = $('#txtto').val();
        var terminalId = $('#txtMerchantAccounthistory').val();
        var SOFAccount = $('#txtsalesNumber').val();
        var statMsg = $('#drpStatMsg').val();
        var formatedData = '';
        var totalrecords = 0;

        if (txtfrom == "") {
            alert("Select Valid From Date");
            event.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
        if (txtto == "") {
            alert("Select Valid To Date");
            event.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }

        var source = {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'Id' },
                { name: 'TerminalId' },
                { name: 'UserName' },
                { name: 'Error' },
                { name: 'Date' },
                { name: 'SalesAccount' },
                { name: 'BillTypeCode' },
                { name: 'Amount' },
                { name: 'BillerCode' },
                { name: 'BankID' },
                { name: 'ReqId' }

            ],
            sort: function () {
                $("#grid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'sort');
            },
            filter: function () {
                $("#grid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'filter');
            },
            beforeprocessing: function (data) {
                var returnData = {};
                data = data.d;
                totalrecords = data.count;
                returnData.totalrecords = data.count;
                returnData.records = data.data;
                if (data.data != null) {
                    return returnData;
                }

                return data;

            },
            type: 'Get',
            sortcolumn: 'Id',
            sortdirection: 'desc',
            formatdata: function (data) {
                data.pagenum = data.pagenum || 0;
                data.pagesize = data.pagesize || 10;
                data.sortdatafield = data.sortdatafield;
                data.sortorder = data.sortorder || 'asc';
                data.filterscount = data.filterscount || 0;
                formatedData = buildQueryString(data);
                return formatedData;
            },
            url: '/WS/WS.asmx/SearchTransferLog',
            data: { fromDate: JSON.stringify(txtfrom), toDate: JSON.stringify(txtto), terminalId: JSON.stringify(terminalId), SOFAccount: JSON.stringify(SOFAccount), statMsg: JSON.stringify(statMsg) },
        };

        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });


        var cols = [
            { text: 'Id', dataField: 'Id', hidden: true },
            { text: 'رقم حساب التاجر', dataField: 'TerminalId', width: '28%', align: "right", cellsalign: "right", hidden: true },
            { text: '', dataField: 'UserName', width: '28%', align: "right", cellsalign: "right", hidden: true },
            { text: 'الحالة', dataField: 'Error', width: '28%', align: "right", cellsalign: "right" },
            { text: 'تاريخ الدفع', dataField: 'Date', width: '18%', align: "right", cellsalign: "right" },
            { text: 'حساب الدفع', dataField: 'SalesAccount', width: '15%', align: "right", cellsalign: "right" },
            { text: 'توقعات الاغلاق على', dataField: 'BillTypeCode', width: '15%', align: "right", cellsalign: "right", hidden: true },
            { text: 'القيمة المحولة', dataField: 'Amount', width: '15%', align: "right", cellsalign: "right" },
            { text: 'توقعات الاغلاق على', dataField: 'BillerCode', width: '15%', align: "right", cellsalign: "right", hidden: true },
            { text: 'توقعات الاغلاق على', dataField: 'BankID', width: '15%', align: "right", cellsalign: "right", hidden: true },
            { text: 'توقعات الاغلاق على', dataField: 'ReqId', width: '15%', align: "right", cellsalign: "right", hidden: true },
            {
                text: '', datafield: 'Edit', columntype: 'button', width: '100px', cellsrenderer: function () {
                    return "استعلام عن الحالة";
                }, buttonclick: function (row) {
                    var id = $("#detail_grid").jqxGrid('getcellvalue', row, "Id");
                    alert(id);
                    //RefreshTransferStatus();
                }
            }

        ];

        $("#detail_grid").jqxGrid({
            source: dataAdapter,
            pageable: true,
            autoheight: true,
            virtualmode: true,
            sorttogglestates: 1,
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            rtl: true,
            altrows: true,
            width: '100%',
            rendergridrows: function (args) {
                return args.data;
            },
            columns: cols
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems that you use `jqxGrid` and **not** `jqGrid`

Comment: yes sorry for mistak

Comment: I changed the jqxGrid to jqGrid in the title, text and in the tag of the question. If you use wrong tag, then the people who could help you will don't see your question. So it's really important to use correct tag of the question and to use correct title.